# Preventing matrix contents from changing after assignment

Tags: matrix

I have two matrices, lets say

```
Rs = ConstantArray[0,{1, 3}];
mat = ConstantArray[0, {1, 3}];

Rs[[1, 1]] = ax + b;
Rs[[1, 2]] = cx + d;
Rs[[1, 3]] = ex + f;

i=0.;
For[x = 1, x < 4, x++,
 i = i + 1;
 mat[[1, i]] = Rs[[1, i]];];
```

As a result; I get

```
Rs[[1, 1]] = 4 a + b; Rs[[1, 2]] = 4 c + d; Rs[[1, 3]] = 4 e + f;
```

but I want

```
mat[[1, 1]] = a + b; mat[[1, 2]] = 2 c + d; mat[[1, 3]]= 3 e + f;
```

which means it does not enforce to change the previous `mat` matrix elements while calculating for the new one. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The code that you post does not produce what you say. But the following does.

```
Rs=ConstantArray[0,{1,3}];
mat = ConstantArray[0, {1, 3}];

Rs[[1, 1]] = a x + b;
Rs[[1, 2]] = c x + d;
Rs[[1, 3]] = e x + f;

i = 0;
For[x = 1, x < 4, x++,
  i = i + 1;
  mat[[1, i]] = Rs[[1, i]];
  ];
```

What is happening here? Well, the value of `x` changes in each iteration of the for loop; but at the end its value is `4`. And this gets substituted in each matrix entry of `Rs` when calling `Rs` afterwards.

You may obtain your desired behavior, e.g., by using `Replace` (`/.`) to substitute values of `x` only locally.

```
Rs = ConstantArray[0, {1, 3}];
mat = ConstantArray[0, {1, 3}];

ClearAll[x];
Rs[[1, 1]] = a x + b;
Rs[[1, 2]] = c x + d;
Rs[[1, 3]] = e x + f;

Do[
 mat[[1, i]] = Rs[[1, i]] /. {x -> i},
 {i, 1, 3}
 ]
```